# ASP.Net Identity using DevExpress ORM instead of Entity Framework

Tags: devexpress, identity

I'm implementing ASP.Net Identity for my MVC web application. 
Could someone profide hints on how to use DevEx ORM and not Entity Framework?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I got reply from DevEx saying that it is currently not possible, and that they created developer ticket for this... we'll see

Answer (score 0):

I got this answer from DevEx team:

Hi Muris,

ASP.NET Identity Framework is highly dependable on the Entity Framework, therefore it is required to write a lot of custom code to utilize it with other ORM. What we plan to do in the context of the  Add support for VS2013 authentication modes ticket is to support selecting the ASP.NET Identity as an authentication provider when creating a new project using the Project Wizard. Since our Project Wizard uses Entity Framework as a data provider, we will also use it to support the ASP.NET Identity authentication.